# C raw socket function fails

Tags: c, embedded

I am new to C programming (as you can probably tell from the code) I wanted to make a function to send data instead of putting it inline, when it's inline it works but when it's a function it fails and I don't know why. The code is running on an ESP32 chip.

Inline

```
void wifi_scan(void) {

    uint16_t number = DEFAULT_SCAN_LIST_SIZE;
    wifi_ap_record_t ap_info[DEFAULT_SCAN_LIST_SIZE];

    uint16_t loop_count = 0;

    uint16_t seen_before = 0;
    const char *ch_arr[18] = {};
    const char * ( *ptr )[18] = &ch_arr;

    const char *prev_ch_arr[18] = {};
    const char * ( *prev_ptr )[18] = &prev_ch_arr;

    while (loop_count < 9) {
            uint16_t ap_count = 0;
            memset(ap_info, 0, sizeof(ap_info));

            esp_wifi_set_mode(WIFI_MODE_STA);
            esp_wifi_start();
            esp_wifi_scan_start(NULL, true);
            esp_wifi_scan_get_ap_records(&number, ap_info);
            esp_wifi_scan_get_ap_num(&ap_count);

            //char rx_buffer[128];
            char host_ip[] = HOST_IP_ADDR;
            int addr_family = 0;
            int ip_protocol = 0;

            struct sockaddr_in dest_addr;
            dest_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(host_ip);
            dest_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
            dest_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
            addr_family = AF_INET;
            ip_protocol = IPPROTO_IP;

            int sock =  socket(addr_family, SOCK_STREAM, ip_protocol);
            connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&dest_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6));

            for (int i = 0; (i < DEFAULT_SCAN_LIST_SIZE) && (i < ap_count); i++) {
                    ( *ptr )[i] = &ap_info[i].ssid;
                    char buf[60];
                    //snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%s:%s:%d", SYSTEM_TAG, ap_info[i].ssid, ap_info[i].rssi);
                    snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%s#%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x#%s#%d$", SYSTEM_TAG, ap_info[i].bssid[0], ap_info[i].bssid[1], ap_info[i].bssid[2], ap_info[i].bssid[3], ap_info[i].bssid[4], ap_info[i].bssid[5], ap_info[i].ssid, ap_info[i].rssi);
                    ESP_LOGI("LOG", "%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x#%s#%d$", ap_info[i].bssid[0], ap_info[i].bssid[1], ap_info[i].bssid[2], ap_info[i].bssid[3], ap_info[i].bssid[4], ap_info[i].bssid[5], ap_info[i].ssid, ap_info[i].rssi);
                    
                    char* *input = buf;
                    unsigned char output[64];
                    size_t outlen;
                    mbedtls_base64_encode(output, 64, &outlen, input, strlen(input));
                    //static const char *payload = "YES";
                    send(sock, output, strlen((const char*) output), 0);
                    send(sock, "\n", strlen("\n"), 0);        
            }
            shutdown(sock, 0);
            close(sock);
            loop_count++;
    }
    get_sleep_time();
    prepareAndGoToDeepSleep();
  }
```

The function I want to use

```
void send_data( char buf ) { 
    char host_ip[] = HOST_IP_ADDR;
    int addr_family = 0;
    int ip_protocol = 0;

    struct sockaddr_in dest_addr;
    dest_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(host_ip);
    dest_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    dest_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    addr_family = AF_INET;
    ip_protocol = IPPROTO_IP;

    int sock =  socket(addr_family, SOCK_STREAM, ip_protocol);
    connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&dest_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6));
    char* *input = buf;
    unsigned char output[64];
    size_t outlen;
    mbedtls_base64_encode(output, 64, &outlen, input, strlen(input));
    send(sock, output, strlen((const char*) output), 0);
    send(sock, "\n", strlen("\n"), 0);
    shutdown(sock, 0);
    close(sock);
}
```

I would like to use it like this

```
( *ptr )[i] = &ap_info[i].ssid;
char buf[60];
snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%s#%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x#%s#%d$", SYSTEM_TAG, ap_info[i].bssid[0], ap_info[i].bssid[1], ap_info[i].bssid[2], ap_info[i].bssid[3], ap_info[i].bssid[4], ap_info[i].bssid[5], ap_info[i].ssid, ap_info[i].rssi);
send_data(buf);
```

IT compiles ok but when I run the code it just fails no console error just CPU reboots

```
rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:2
load:0x3fff0030,len:5668
load:0x40078000,len:14344
load:0x40080400,len:3748
0x40080400: _init at ??:?
```

Comment: `char buf` contains a single character, not a buffer.  And the compiler should complain about `char* *input = buf;`.

Comment: Thanks! Should it be send_data(char buf[60]) then?

Comment: or maybe `send_data(char *buf)`

Comment: As an aside: In some cases (e.g. when you also want to send binary data, which is probably not your current use case), it is more "generic" to have something like `size_t send_data(void* data, size_t data_length)`. Then the caller has to do the `strlen()` call in your case, but you can also send substrings or other binary data, not relying on 0 termination. Also, sometimes, you cannot send arbirtrarily long strings with 1 call (depends on the systems tcp-stack and its limitations). And the return value of my function would return the actual amount of bytes accepted.

Comment: Because you are working with string buffers, the null terminator needs to be included in what is sent, but is not counted when using `strlen()`.  Therefore `send(sock, output, strlen((const char*) output), 0);` I think should just be; `send(sock, output, strlen(output)+1, 0);`